# Updating Points of TVTK Dataset in MayaVI (without flushing pipeline)

Tags: python, visualization, vtk, mayavi

I want to use MayaVI for visualization of large simulation data, saved as a VTKUnstructuredGrid (or here TVTK Unstructured Grid). After loading the Grid, I want to quickly update the grid points using numpy arrays, without changing anything else in the model.

So far I update the points and then call the modified()-method, which flushes the complete pipeline and thus slows down the visualization a lot. My question is now: Is there any chance to update the points in a VTKDataset without reloading the whole pipeline?

I am doing the visualization using Traits; simplified my code looks like:

```
import numpy as np

from enthought.traits.api import HasTraits, Range, Instance, on_trait_change
from enthought.traits.ui.api import View, Item, HGroup, HSplit, VSplit
from enthought.tvtk.pyface.scene_editor import SceneEditor
from enthought.mayavi.tools.mlab_scene_model import MlabSceneModel
from enthought.mayavi.core.ui.mayavi_scene import MayaviScene
from enthought.mayavi import mlab
from enthought.tvtk.api import tvtk
from enthought.mayavi.modules.surface import Surface
from enthought.tvtk.pyface.scene_editor import SceneEditor
class Visu(HasTraits):

  timestep = Range(50,100,50)
  pts = tvtk.Points()
  ugrid = tvtk.UnstructuredGrid()
  scene = Instance(MlabSceneModel, ())
  view = View(Item('scene', editor=SceneEditor(scene_class=MayaviScene), height=250, width=300, show_label=True),HGroup('_', 'timestep'), resizable=True )

  @on_trait_change('scene.activated')
  def ini(self):
    filename = 'original3dplot'
    reader = tvtk.LSDynaReader(file_name = filename)
    reader.update()
    self.ugrid = reader.get_output()
    self.surface = self.scene.mlab.pipeline.surface(self.ugrid)

  @on_trait_change('timestep')
  def update_visu(self):
    update_coord = np.loadtxt('newcoordinates'+str(self.timestep))
    self.pts.from_array(update_coord)
    self.ugrid.points = self.pts
    self.ugrid.modified()

visualization = Visu()
visualization.configure_traits()
```